# Iterating through timestamp in file name

Tags: matlab, loops, iterator, timestamp

I'm working on a project where I'm receiving data from another graduate student, and I have to iterate through each file name and run a quick snippet of code on it. The issue is that the file names I've been given have the time stamp in the file name, and the files weren't created at integer multiples of seconds. My pseudo code:

```
for fileindex = 1:250;

    filename = '/pathname/data_', fileindex, '.mat';
    load(filename); %785 x 32 x 921

    for index1 = 1:32;
        for index2 = 1:921;
            Run code here;
        end
    end
end
```

So I have all of it straightened out, except the timestamp is in the middle of the file name. As an example, here's the first few file names:

scan1_20150507_224251_00001.mat

scan1_20150507_224252_00002.mat

scan1_20150507_224252_00003.mat

scan1_20150507_224253_00004.mat

scan1_20150507_224254_00005.mat

scan1_20150507_224254_00006.mat

scan1_20150507_224255_00007.mat

At some times, there's 2 files per second, and at other times, there's as few as 1 or as many as 4. I have 250 files for now, and on the full dataset I'll have about 7500 files, so I can't feasibly go through and manually change all the file names. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually creating the name of the file and reading it in, it may be prudent to just place all of the files in a single directory, and query all of the files in this directory.  You'd then have a structure of all possible files in the directory, and you can iterate through these names instead.

This way, you avoid having to account for gaps in the time line and you would have access to **all** of the files at once, rather than trying to account for missing data.  In this case, you'd look at it at the file level, and not at the acquisition level.

Using [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) in addition to [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) should work perfectly.  `dir` queries for files in a directory and `fullfile` will help you reconstruct the right path with the right slash operators in order to be operating system agnostic.

Do something like this:

```
folder = fullfile('path', 'to', 'folder'); %// Replace by your folder
f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.mat')); % // Look for the files

for idx = 1 : numel(f) %// For each file

    filename = fullfile(folder, f(idx).name); %// Get the file name
    load(filename); %// Load the file

    for index1 = 1:32;
        for index2 = 1:921;
            %//Run code here;
        end
    end
end
```

For each folder that is separated by a slash, that would serve as a separate string to `fullfile`.  Keep that in mind when modifying the first line of code.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, and it works perfectly. I didn't know it could be done by directory instead of file-by-file. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewM. - Yup!... one of the things I found out eventually.  Glad I could help!  Good luck!